# How do I create columns that evaluate other columns cumulatively?

Tags: 2013, list, custom, conditional

Im very new to SharePoint as a whole so please bear with me.

Currently I am trying to create a checklist on SharePoint 2013 which features about 30 or so odd questions, each to be answered with Yes/No/N.A. These 30 or so questions are further divided into three categories 1, 2 and 3. Since creating a custom list with well >30 columns is unreasonable I thought about just showing the three categories 1, 2 and 3.

Ideally the cells in these columns should show cumulatively whether there was an issue (answered with "No") or not. Let me explain in more detail:

Category 1.X contains 19 of the 30 questions (referred to as tasks). While going through these 19 tasks they are answered with either yes, no or NA. I want the "1.X Vorgaben" column to analyze all of these 19 tasks (which I have hidden from view), and tell if tasks were answered with no. Ideally it would also tell me which task was answered no (so if task 16 was answered no it would say "1.16"). Fields answered yes would naturally not show up. Maybe, if possible this field could turn green or red depending on the situation. Heres an image of how this would work (sorry for it being in german):

[image]

So could anyone suggest a solution for this? I understand that SharePoint Designer has some options regarding conditional formating but my company has blocked it so I am unsure on how to continue...

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list with 30 columns is reasonable, If you go in 100 columns then yes, you should look for alternative. Unfortunately there isn't much you can do with SP out of the box apart form using Infopath (wiht IP the underlying data will be saved in xml). If you create infopath form library you can decide which fields from infopath you want to promote to Sharepoint (in your case that would be cat 1 2 and 3) and with IP functions you can  make necessary calculations on the submit.